# Mysql tables does not reflect new changes

Tags: mysql, command-line, count, create-table

I have created 4 tables by using command line in 'college2' database:

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_college2 |
+--------------------+
| course             |
| enrolment          |
| enrolment_status   |
| student            |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The table `enrolment_status` counts the number of enrolled students in each course, from the table `enrolment`, and is created using the following command line:

```
CREATE TABLE enrolment_status SELECT code, count(id) FROM enrolment
GROUP BY code;
```

When i insert a new record to `enrolment` table, i expect to see a corresponding change in `enrolment_status` table, but `enrolment_status` table remains unchanged, does not reflect newly inserted record.

How should i correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `CREATE TABLE` with another table as the data source provides the target table with a one time snapshot of the data in the source table.  Hence, making subsequent inserts into `enrolment` will not reflect in `enrolment_status`.  The closest thing to what you have in mind might be to create a view on top of the `enrolment` table:

```
CREATE VIEW enrolment_view AS
SELECT code, COUNT(id)
FROM enrolment
GROUP BY code;
```

The view `enrolment_view` would reflect changes to the underlying table `enrolment`, including newly inserted records.  But, it would not be possible to insert records directly into this view.

Comment: Tim, it worked beautifully as you said. Thank you very much for help!